# What is Namespace in salesforce?

Tags: namespace

What is meant by namespace generally and why we are using in salesforce.

By using Namespace what we'll do in salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

> Namespace prefixes are used in managed Force.com AppExchange packages
>   to differentiate custom object and field names from those in use by
>   other organizations.

After registering aunique namespace object or field api name will look like

```
namespace_prefix__object_or_field_name__c
```

It is very usefull feature so that the API name of Manage package should not conflict with native fields API Name.

Find more on [Namespace doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm)